# Is there a better way to write this SQL code? I want to alert when the Po_lines_location_all latest record is satisfying the where condition

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-apps

I want to display alert message for the latest update record on a table if it satisfies a condition.

```
Select PO_HEADERS_ALL.SEGMENT1 ,po_line_locations_all.PO_LINE_ID, PO_LINES_ALL.LINE_NUM ,PO_LINE_LOCATIONS_ALL.QUANTITY ,PO_LINE_LOCATIONS_ALL.QUANTITY_RECEIVED,po_line_locations_all.Price_Override,
po_line_locations_all.CREATION_DATE 
INTO 
&OUTPUT1,&OUTPUT2,&OUTPUT3,&OUTPUT4,&OUTPUT5,&OUTPUT6,&OUTPUT7
FROM ((PO_LINE_LOCATIONS_ALL
INNER JOIN PO_LINES_ALL 
ON PO_LINE_LOCATIONS_ALL.PO_LINE_ID= PO_LINES_ALL.PO_LINE_ID)
INNER JOIN PO_HEADERS_ALL 
ON PO_LINE_LOCATIONS_ALL.PO_HEADER_ID= PO_HEADERS_ALL.PO_HEADER_ID)
where 
PO_LINE_LOCATIONS_ALL.Last_update_date = (select max(LAST_UPDATE_DATE) from PO_LINE_LOCATIONS_ALL WHERE  po_line_locations_all.QUANTITY_RECEIVED>(po_line_locations_all.QUANTITY*0.10)+ po_line_locations_all.QUANTITY
AND rowid=:rowid)
```